# How to add a new variable in different data frames using for?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have different data frames  "dsub_i_j"

```
i= 316,  325, 1101, 1349, 1544, ...
j= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

dsub_101_1
dsub_101_2
.
.
dsub_101_8
dsub_316_1
dsub_316_2
.
.
.
```

I would like add the same variable in each data_frame:

I mean do this for each j:

```
# j= 101 

dsub_101_1$orden_grupo=seq(1, nrow(dsub_101_1), by = 1)
dsub_101_2$orden_grupo=seq(1, nrow(dsub_101_2), by = 1)
dsub_101_3$orden_grupo=seq(1, nrow(dsub_101_3), by = 1)
dsub_101_4$orden_grupo=seq(1, nrow(dsub_101_4), by = 1)
dsub_101_5$orden_grupo=seq(1, nrow(dsub_101_5), by = 1)
dsub_101_6$orden_grupo=seq(1, nrow(dsub_101_6), by = 1)
dsub_101_7$orden_grupo=seq(1, nrow(dsub_101_7), by = 1)
dsub_101_8$orden_grupo=seq(1, nrow(dsub_101_8), by = 1)
```

and then paste together each group.

```
dsub_101=rbind(dsub_101_1,dsub_101_2,dsub_101_3,dsub_101_4,dsub_101_5,  
               dsub_101_6,dsub_101_7,dsub_101_8)

dsub_101$orden=seq(1, nrow(dsub_101), by = 1)
```

and save each one in setwd.

I try this but doesnt work. :(

```
 grupo_fict_groups = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
 cod_jer_grups= c(101,  316,  325, 1349, 1544,...)

 for(i in cod_jer_groups ){
 for(j in grupo_fict_groups){

    dsub_i_j$orden_grupo=seq(1, nrow(dsub_i_j), by = 1)

   }}
```

any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: why do you think the for loop will run with that code!

Comment: You can also `df2 <- do.call("rbind", mget("dsub_101")` and add the index after with `df2$orden_grupo <- sapply(mget("dsub_101"), function(x) 1:nrow(x))`

Comment: because I have more dan 100 data frames with the same variable, i dont know another way to do it

Comment: How can I add a variable in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a function that will bind the dataframes together and add an id column could help the iteration.

```
rbind.id <- function(..., id.col="orden_grupo") {
  args <- list(...)
  dfs <- if(length(args) == 1 && is.list(args[[1]])) args[[1]] else args
  df2 <- do.call("rbind", dfs)
  df2[,id.col] <- unlist(lapply(dfs, function(x) 1:nrow(x)))
  return(df2)
}
```

The new `rbind.id` function does what the regular rbind does but also adds an id for each df. Next we can wrap this function in an lapply loop to cycle over multiple data frame groups.

```
multi.bind <- function(patterns) {
  lapply(patterns, function(p) rbind.id(mget(ls(pattern=p, envir=.GlobalEnv),envir=.GlobalEnv)))
}
```

This multi.bind function accepts a vector of patterns as input. These are the `dsub_i` labels in your example. A possible loop might be:

```
i <- c(316,  325, 1101, 1349, 1544)
allgrps <- paste0("dsub_", i)
multi.bind(patterns=allgrps)
```

Comment: I dont understan whats mean "..."  inside function??

Comment: An example. I can enter `paste("a", "b")` and get back `"a b"`. Those are two arguments in the function. I can enter `paste("a", "b", "c", 1, "hello")` and get back `"a b c 1 hello"`. There is no limit to the number of arguments I can enter. What makes this possible is `paste <- function(...)`. It allows the user to enter however many arguments they want.

Comment: Perfect! But if I need to paste dsub_101_1, dsub_101_2... dsub_101_8, Can I do it automatic way? I mean:       `dsub_101=rbind.id(dsub_101_1,dsub_101_2,dsub_101_3,dsub_101_4,dsub_101_5,dsub_101_6,dsub_101_7,dsub_101_8)` may be with a for?

Comment: That's what multibind does.

Comment: I dont know how to put boths codes to make i work... :(

Comment: This is all you need `multi.bind("dsub_101")`. It will look for all of the dataframes with that prefix.

Comment: You're welcome. One way to say thanks for a solution is to check the answer as accepted.

Comment: Last question: If I would call automatic cod_jer_groups `cod_jer_grups= c(101,  316,  325, 1349, 1544,...)` and generate differents data frames can I do it like that:
     `for(i in cod_jer_groups) {
     dsub=as.data.frame(multi.bind("dsub==dsub[which(cod_jer_groups==i)])")
assign_string = paste("dsub",cod_jer_groups[which(cod_jer_groups==i),sep = "_")
assign(assign_string,base)
 }`

Comment: No. Instead use something like `lapply(cod_jer_grups, function(x) multi.bind(paste0("dsub_", x)))`

Comment: Actually, it's easier than that. I forgot that multi.bind accepts many groups at the same time. `multi.bind(paste0("dsub_", cod_jer_grups))`

Comment: Who would be "x"?

Comment: Don't use the `lapply` function I added. multi.bind can handle multiple groups